# Simpler electron app update without full download

Tags: electron, electron-updater

I have an windows electron app (around 250 megs) and i need it be updated once in a while. The only thing that is changing is index.js which is around 350 kb. Is there a simpler solution than downloading entire package with every auto update?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look at [Hydraulic Conveyor](https://hydraulic.dev/), it has full support for delta updates on Windows and Mac and is IMHO simpler than using Forge. It doesn't rely on Squirrel for updates and has a variety of other features that you might find useful. Just be aware that it's only free for open source projects, for commercial it's a paid tool.

Disclosure: My company makes Conveyor.